# C# penultimate of a number

Tags: c#, text, numbers, any

So my question is how can I retrieve the penultimate digit of the number that the user wrote down? Below is my code so far:

```
Console.Write("Write a numeral: ");
string s = Console.ReadLine();
int a = int.Parse(s);
```

Comment: string s = Console.ReadLine();

Comment: Ahm yes my bad, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean penultimate digit in the number then

```
var penultimate = (a / 10) % 10;
```

should give you the value.

However, it's also highly advisable to check if the number has at least 2 digits

```
a => 10 || a <= -10
```

And also handle the possibility that the input is not a number.